# X11 forward ssh Visual studio remote connection

Tags: linux, visual-studio, x11, x11-forwarding

I’am able to compile and build a Linux application remotely to a raspberry pi. It would help me if I can debug aswell.

The problem is when I try to debug with visual studio and just before the application is about to launch I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

I am aware that it has something to do with remotely starting a graphical application. A solution would be to start the ssh connection with -X or -Y parameter.

Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn’t let me add arguments in the ssh connection.

Is there a way to add those arguments?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the information provided. The issue above is part of the development process and therefore in my opinion on-topic. Luckily i have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and I'am able to debug a GUI application remotely from Visual Studio to a Linux machine(Raspberry PI).

The remote machine has to know on what display the application to run.

Add `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to the Configuration Properties–>Debugging–>Pre-Launch Command setting so the Linux machine knows which display to show the window on.